# How to generate temporary URLs in Django

Tags: django, url

Wondering if there is a good way to generate temporary URLs that expire in X days.  Would like to email out a URL that the recipient can click to access a part of the site that then is inaccessible via that URL after some time period.  No idea how to do this, with Django, or Python, or otherwise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you don't expect to get a large response rate, then you should try to store all of the data in the URL itself.  This way, you don't need to store anything in the database, and will have data storage proportional to the responses rather than the emails sent.

Updated: Let's say you had two strings that were unique for each user.  You can pack them and unpack them with a protecting hash like this:

```
import hashlib, zlib
import cPickle as pickle
import urllib

my_secret = "michnorts"

def encode_data(data):
    """Turn `data` into a hash and an encoded string, suitable for use with `decode_data`."""
    text = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(data, 0)).encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
    m = hashlib.md5(my_secret + text).hexdigest()[:12]
    return m, text

def decode_data(hash, enc):
    """The inverse of `encode_data`."""
    text = urllib.unquote(enc)
    m = hashlib.md5(my_secret + text).hexdigest()[:12]
    if m != hash:
        raise Exception("Bad hash!")
    data = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(text.decode('base64')))
    return data

hash, enc = encode_data(['Hello', 'Goodbye'])
print hash, enc
print decode_data(hash, enc)
```

This produces:

```
849e77ae1b3c eJzTyCkw5ApW90jNyclX5yow4koMVnfPz09JqkwFco25EvUAqXwJnA==
['Hello', 'Goodbye']
```

In your email, include a URL that has both the hash and enc values (properly url-quoted).  In your view function, use those two values with decode_data to retrieve the original data.

The zlib.compress may not be that helpful, depending on your data, you can experiment to see what works best for you.

Comment: Basically each URL would be for one user to access, so not a large response rate.  This idea sounds interesting but I'm not quite getting it 100%--a small example would be great!

Comment: Nowadays, Django provides tools that can produce a "URL-safe, signed base64 compressed JSON string" with timestamp: [Django Cryptographic signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signing/#module-django.core.signing).

Answer (score 5):

You could set this up with URLs like:

```
http://yoursite.com/temp/1a5h21j32
```

Your URLconf would look something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^temp/(?P<hash>\w+)/$', 'yoursite.views.tempurl'),
)
```

...where tempurl is a view handler that fetches the appropriate page based on the hash.  Or, sends a 404 if the page is expired.

Answer (score 5):

models

```
class TempUrl(models.Model):
    url_hash = models.CharField("Url", blank=False, max_length=32, unique=True)
    expires = models.DateTimeField("Expires")
```

views

```
def generate_url(request):
    # do actions that result creating the object and mailing it

def load_url(request, hash):
    url = get_object_or_404(TempUrl, url_hash=hash, expires__gte=datetime.now())
    data = get_some_data_or_whatever()
    return render_to_response('some_template.html', {'data':data}, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^temp/(?P<hash>\w+)/$', 'your.views.load_url', name="url"),)
```

//of course you need some imports and templates

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do - one-shot things like account activation or allowing a file to be downloaded could be done with a view which looks up a hash, checks a timestamp and performs an action or provides a file.

More complex stuff such as providing arbitrary data would also require the model containing some reference to that data so that you can decide what to send back.  Finally, allowing access to multiple pages would probably involve setting something in the user's session and then using that to determine what they can see, followed by a redirect.

If you could provide more detail about what you're trying to do and how well you know Django, I can make a more specific reply.

Comment: What I want to do is provide access to a form via the temporary URL, so the targeted visitor could go to the URL within X days (before link expires) and it would bring up the form.  The form would be prepopulated with data that would differ with each URL generated.  So same form, different data per URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution lies within a combination of all the suggested solutions. I'd suggest using an expiring session so the link will expire within the time period you specify in the model. Combined with a redirect and middleware to check if a session attribute exists and the requested url requires it you can create somewhat secure parts of your site that can have nicer URLs that reference permanent parts of the site. I use this for demonstrating design/features for a limited time. This works to prevent forwarding... I don't do it but you could remove the temp url after first click so only the session attribute will provide access thus more effectively limiting to one user. I personally don't mind if the temp url gets forwarded knowing it will only last for a certain amount of time. Works well in a modified form for tracking invited visits as well.

Comment: Interesting. Not sure I get the method to prevent forwarding, would love to hear more detail on that approach.

Comment: what i mean by forwarding is someone sending a link to someone else. You set the cookie once and flag it set in your app such that anyone else accessing the URL won't have access because they don't have the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill, but you could use a uuidfield on your model and set up a Celerybeat task to change the uuid at any time interval you choose. 
If celery is too much and it might be, you could just store the time the URL is first sent, use the timedelta function whenever it is sent thereafter, and if the elapsed time is greater than what you want just use a redirect. I think the second solution is very straightforward and it would extend easily. It would be a matter of having a model with the URL, time first sent, time most recently sent, a disabled flag, and a Delta that you find acceptable for the URL to live.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary url can also be created by combining the ideas from [@ned-batchelder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1360222) and [@matt-howell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1360120) with [Django's `signing` module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signing/).

The `signing` module provides a convenient way to encode data in the url, if necessary, and to check for link expiration. This way we don't need to touch the database or session/cache.

Here's a minimal example with an index page and a temp page:

The index page has a link to a temporary url, with the specified expiration. If you try to follow the link after expiration, you'll get a status 400 "Bad Request" (or you'll see the `SuspiciousOperation` error, if `DEBUG` is `True`).

#### urls.py

```py
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:signed_data>/', views.temp, name='temp'),
]
```

#### views.py

```py
from django.core import signing
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse

MAX_AGE_SECONDS = 20  # short expiration, for illustrative purposes


def generate_temp_url(data=None):
    # signing.dumps() returns a "URL-safe, signed base64 compressed JSON string"
    # with a timestamp
    return reverse('temp', args=[signing.dumps(data)])


def index(request):
    # just a convenient usage example
    return HttpResponse(f'<a href="{generate_temp_url()}">temporary link</a>')


def temp(request, signed_data):
    try:
        # load data and check expiration
        data = signing.loads(signed_data, max_age=MAX_AGE_SECONDS)
    except signing.BadSignature:
        # triggers an HttpResponseBadRequest (status 400) when DEBUG is False
        raise SuspiciousOperation('invalid signature')
    # success
    return HttpResponse(f'Here\'s your data: {data}')
```

Some notes:

- The responses in the example are very rudimentary, and only for illustrative purposes.
- Raising a `SuspiciousOperation` is convenient, but you could e.g. return an `HttpResponseNotFound` (status 404) instead.
- The `generate_temp_url()` returns a relative path. If you need an absolute url, you can do something like:

  ```py
  temp_url = request.build_absolute_uri(generate_temp_url())
  ```
- If you're worried about leaking the signed data, have a look at alternatives such as Django's [password reset implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/46b28bbe151282e9198b719d00f84b48c92606ba/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L267).