# Generate temporary URLs in Django 2 Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

There is one same question in StackOverflow with this link:
[How to generate temporary URLs in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360101/how-to-generate-temporary-urls-in-django)

But the accepted answer code is for Python 2 and I converted it to Python 3:

```
import hashlib, zlib
import pickle as pickle
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

my_secret = "michnorts"

def encode_data(data):
    """Turn `data` into a hash and an encoded string, suitable for use with `decode_data`."""
    text = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(data, 0)).encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
    m = hashlib.md5(my_secret + text).hexdigest()[:12]
    return m, text

def decode_data(hash, enc):
    """The inverse of `encode_data`."""
    text = urllib.parse.unquote(enc)
    m = hashlib.md5(my_secret + text).hexdigest()[:12]
    if m != hash:
        raise Exception("Bad hash!")
    data = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(text.decode('base64')))
    return data

hash, enc = encode_data(['Hello', 'Goodbye'])
print(hash, enc)
print(decode_data(hash, enc))
```

But it have error :

```
    text = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(data, 0)).encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Please check the python documentation about the `byte` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to adapt your code to Python 3, I came up with this:

```
import hashlib, zlib
import pickle as pickle
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import base64

my_secret = "michnorts"

def encode_data(data):
    """Turn `data` into a hash and an encoded string, suitable for use with `decode_data`."""
    compressed_text = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(data, 0))
    text = base64.b64encode(compressed_text).decode().replace('\n', '')
    m = hashlib.md5(str.encode('{}{}'.format(my_secret, text))).hexdigest()[:12]
    return m, text

def decode_data(hash, enc):
    """The inverse of `encode_data`."""
    text = urllib.parse.unquote(enc)
    m = hashlib.md5(str.encode('{}{}'.format(my_secret, text))).hexdigest()[:12]
    if m != hash:
        raise Exception("Bad hash!")
    data = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(text)))
    return data

hash, enc = encode_data(['Hello', 'Goodbye'])
print(hash, enc)
print(decode_data(hash, enc))
```

There are some things that I needed to take into account:

- in Python 3, the way to encode/decode into base64 is by using the [base64 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)
- to cast a `bytes` object into a string, I used the [bytes.decode method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)
- to cast a string object into a `bytes` object, I used the [str.encode function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)
- the `hashlib.md5` function accepts a `bytes`object (strings need to be previously encoded)
- I changed the way you concatenate strings (i.e. `str1 + str2`) with a more pythonic construction: `'{}{}'.format(str1, str2)`

I hope this will be helpful ;)

Comment: Just one more additional info : `zlib.compress` returns `string` in python2 and `bytes` in python3.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the built-in *secrets* modules, especially [secrets.token_urlsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_urlsafe).