# Logging to other sites using temporary url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm making a password manager and was wondering how to generate a temporary link(that expires for example after 5 min) that takes login and password of the website that user has stored in the manager and allows someone to login into this account. Is there any way to do it because quite frankly I have no idea how to make it work.

thanks for help :)

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question? Maybe you can give an example of how this process would work. Like:
1) User A generates temp link for login to web page X using the password manager |
2) User B gets the link and enters it into browser |
3) User B is logged in to User As account at web page X |
If this was the question then I see all kinds of trouble with this, be it different login mechanism or, most importantly, security issues.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. Basically all you just said is what I meant, and yes I agree that it's not the most secure way, but I'm trying to make it as recruitment task and these are the acceptance criteria for it, so I can't really do it differently.

Comment: This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360101/how-to-generate-temporary-urls-in-django is close to what you are asking. I have not tested it myself, so you can try out and let me know.